# USB opendevice fails even if it has permission - HostAPI is restricted

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I'm trying to connect Android and Arduino UNO using the Android USB Host API.
I discover the device using an `intent-filter`.
I obtain the appropriate `UsbInterface` and `UsbEndpoint`. Everything seems fine until I try opening the `UsbDeviceConnection`, **which always fails despite permissions are granted**.
What's the reason?

Snippet below:

```
       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
           Intent intent = getIntent();
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
               device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
           }
       }

       public boolean connect(UsbDevice device){

       [...] // search for appropriate interfaces/endpoints

       Log.i(TAG, "usbInEndpoint = " + usbInEndpoint.toString());
       Log.i(TAG, "usbOutEndpoint = " + usbOutEndpoint.toString());
       Log.i(TAG, "usbInterface = " + usbInterface.toString());
       Log.i(TAG, "permission = " + usbManager.hasPermission(device));

       usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(device); 
       Log.i(TAG, "usbDeviceConnection = " + usbDeviceConnection));

       [...]

       }
```

Logcat extract below:

```
usbInEndpoint = UsbEndpoint[mAddress=131,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]
usbOutEndpoint = UsbEndpoint[mAddress=4,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]
usbInterface = UsbInterface[mId=1,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=10,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[
    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=4,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]
    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=131,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]]
permission = true

D/UsbService: openDevice(/dev/bus/usb/001/002) : HostAPI is restricted

usbDeviceConnection = null
```

**EDIT**

I edited the question and the Logcat extract because I noticed UsbService logs that "Host API is restricted" after I call opendevice, so I guess is kind of device security setting. How to check that? I'm using Samsung A8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question hoping this would be helpful for others with same issue. This was due to my mobile being managed by a MDM.